# Using information from one table to set information in another

Tags: sql, database

A little more information on the problem I was given the task to set data in one table based on the AVG scores of data from a different table. For instance using the tables here.

| id | task_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 100 |
| 2 | 74 | 78 |
| 3 | 33 | 50 |
| 4 | 74 | 75 |
| 5 | 33 | 50 |

| id | AVG score |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | null |
| 74 | null |

I was wondering how one could go about simply setting the AVG scores to the averages of the matching task_id to id in the two tables. So just to clarify id 33's AVG score should be 66.667. The test is already over I just really want to know how one would go about doing this my attempts yielded results like aggregate functions not usable in UPDATE queries. Thanks

Comment: check out here how to update with joins, in our case you'll need to include the AVG aggregate function as well. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **aggregate** functions for getting average scores inside of the **UPDATE** query.

The query might look something similar to this:

```
UPDATE Table2 AS t2
SET Avg_Score = (SELECT AVG(Score) 
                 FROM Table1
                 WHERE taskId=t2.Id
                 GROUP BY Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As generic SQL, you would use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Table2
    SET Avg_Score = (SELECT AVG(t1.Score) 
                     FROM Table1 t1
                     WHERE t1.taskId = table2.Id
                    );
```

Some things to note:

- This updates *all* rows in `Table2`.  If there are no matches, the value is `NULL`.
- Some databases will calculate the average of an integer *as an integer*.  To be safe, you might want `SELECT AVG(t1.Score * 1.0)`.
- I do not recommend actually storing such information.  It is simple to calculate and you can use a view if you want something that "looks" like a table.